# Relational Data Modeling question - 2 different tables needing the same "sub-data"

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, relational-database

I've read many of the answers here about 1-1 relationships, modeling object-type relationships, etc.   I am trying to do something that I'm just not sure what is the right way.

I have 2 different tables that both need to reference/contain lists of polygons (the polygon is actually represented as an outer loop and any number of inner loops to represent holes in the surface).  Each of the 2 tables is a completely different set of attributes.

Here is a view of the model with only 1 table referencing the polygons:

[image]

Now I want to have a second table that each row also represents a collection of of polygons.  I know how to do this from an Object-oriented point of view, but the relational view has me confused as to what is the right way.

One way is to add another foreign key to the polygonwitholes table, and one is null while the other is populated.  That is shown here:

[image]

This just doesn't seem right.  So I thought about an intermediate table, but the relationships seem more object-oriented than relational.  Is this an unreasonable way to do it, to have an either/or on those foreign keys?  or I could have one field that is an integer and not add any constraint to the database that it is a foreign key to another table, and use it for whichever table is used at that time?   From a query perspective, I will have to retrieve all the points in each of the polygons for a row in either table1 or table2.

So one of the options I came up with was this, but then I think about how to do queries, and something just doesn't seem right:

[image]

I know that for a true data modeler, this will be an obvious question!   This site has been great for me, this is my first question, and I hope it makes sense!   So are there any suggestions of how this should be modeled?

(Ok, I tried to post, but the images didn't come up. Going to try to get someone to post them for me)

Comment: "Now I want to have a second table that each row also represents a collection of of polygons." You said you want a collection of polygons, but you seem to be trying to implement a collection of polygons with holes. (Not sure; can't see images yet.) Which is it?

Comment: Ok, I can see images now. If I were going to make a collection of polygons with holes, I'd make a table, and I'd put the keys of polygons with holes in that table. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: The "polygon with holes" represents the real life object this way: for each row in "table1" (call it "surface"), there are multiple rows in "polygon with holes", one must be specified as the outer loop, and the others describe the holes.  Then, for each polygon, there are multiple rows in points.   My question more has to do with how to handle table1 and table2.  One of these is "surface", and it will have attributes about things like materials, textures, etc, associated with it.   Table2 is a sensor grid, which has a whole different set of things than a surface (like a normal vector, etc).

Comment: Both of these things are geometrically represented by the polygon with holes.  In an object oriented world, I'd have a class like "PolygonContainer" and the Surface and Grid would both inherit from that class, as they are both representations of polygons. My question is how to do this in a relational way, and I don't think either of my ideas is quite right. Right now I know the Polygon Container table is wrong, it's like I've mixed relational and object concepts in the wrong way here

Comment: UPDATE TO QUESTION: So I've been looking more, thinking more, an I'm wondering if what I need are intermediate tables to define a m-m relationship? So I can have a Table1_PolygonWithHoles table and a Table2_PolygonWithHoles table, so that the relationship is separated from those tables? Is this a more normalized way to do this? I know I will have to do joins, but is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made a decision after consulting with people.

I went with the 3rd-normal form and made intermediate tables to tie the surfaces to polygons and the grids to polygons.  The final solution has the following tables:

Surface (ID primary key)
SensorGrid (ID primary key)

Polygon(ID primary key)
Point(ID primary key, PolygonID foreign key)

Surface_Polygon(surfaceID, polygonID: composite primary key)
SensorGrid_Polygon(sensorGridID, polygonID: composite primary key)

So the 2 intermediate tables tie the polygons to whether they are in a grid or a surface.  I will check to make sure the extra join doesn't impact performance too badly.  It is the cleanest solution, and if the performance really needs to be optimized in the future, i will consider making separate tables for SurfacePolygon, SurfacePoint, SensorPolygon, and SensorPoint and get rid of the intermediate tables.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am going to take a stab at this.  If this is truly a 1 to 1 and that a given  PolygonwithHoles cannot be both a surface and a grid then I would use your last example but I would drop the container table is it is completely redundant. That table could always be created using a sql union if for some reason you wanted to get all the polygonwithholes as surfaces and grids.

Comment: That's exactly true, a polygonwithholes cannot be both a grid and a surface. You don't see a problem with using the 2 foreign keys with only one being used?  I was wondering if there was a "union"-like feature like in C programming.  This is MySQL, so I'm not sure.  Thanks.

Comment: I spoke with someone about this, and he suggested I make separate tables for the polygons that are part of a surface and polygons that are part of grid, even though they are the same, because they are true 1-m (a polygon cannot be in both a surface and a grid).  He said for performance reasons this may not be "pure" but if I don't ever need to query ALL polygons for something.   Do you have any suggestions on that?  Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need to query all polygons then I would agree with the person you talked to.